# How to use match function in for loop?

Tags: r, string, text, stringr

The objective is: (1) to extract multiwords/strings (from `data1`), (2) to replace those extracted words by other strings located in another dataset (`data2`).

```
library(stringr)
data1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
          text=c("This is text mining exercise text",
                 "Text analysis is bit confusing analysis",
                 "Hint on this text analysis?")) 
data2 <- data.frame(mult1 = c("text","analysis","bit confusing"),
          mult2 = c("A; B; C","A; D", "A; B; C; D"))

txt <- subf <- list()
pattern <- tolower(str_c(data2$mult1, collapse = "|"))
for(i in 1:length(data1$id)){ 
  txt[[i]] <- unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(data1$text[i]), pattern))
  j <- match(txt[[i]], data2$mult1) # Here is my problem
  subf[[i]] <- data2$mult2[j]
}
```

How I can change the value of `j` at each iteration & use in `subf[[i]] <- data2$mult2[j]`? Any help is highly appreciated. Tnx!

Comment: Hello Gaddaa, can you please tell us what exactly the problem is. It runs on my computer. What is the desired output and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Jan The code has no error. The problem is `j` is fixed & do not change at each iteration. `j` takes values at first iteration & use it for all. But `j` should take different values at each iteration to proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `j` isn't the problem. The final statement in the loop is. By default R interprets text as factors. So there are two ways to solve it (or at least get closer to a solution).

1. Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when setting the data frame.
2. Type-cast the factor to a character vecor in the loop.

```
# Solution using both approaches at the same time
library(stringr)
data1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
                    text=c("This is text mining exercise text",
                           "Text analysis is bit confusing analysis",
                           "Hint on this text analysis?"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
data2 <- data.frame(mult1 = c("text","analysis","bit confusing"),
                    mult2 = c("A; B; C","A; D", "A; B; C; D"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

txt <- subf <- list()
pattern <- tolower(str_c(data2$mult1, collapse = "|"))

for (i in 1:length(data1$id)) { 
  txt[[i]] <- unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(data1$text[i]), pattern))
  j <- match(txt[[i]], data2$mult1) # Here is NOT problem
  # added as.character()
  subf[[i]] <- as.character(data2$mult2[j]) 
}
```

I am not sure that this is exactly what you wanted because it gives you a nested list. But it correctly recognizes the occurrencies of the key words `data2$mult1`and gets the according value from `data2$mult2`.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. But the `j` should assume different values for each iteration (I mean in the set-up of my problem). The trick still resides in using `match()` function in the loop.

Comment: I can delete the answer if this does not solve it. But when I run it. `j` is `c(1, 1)` in iteration 1, `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` in iteration 2, and `c(1, 2)` in iteration 3. If I understood it correctly, these are the correct indices.

Did you run it?

Comment: Let me restart my pc if that is the problem. Wait, please!

Comment: How do I get those indices? I'm getting `1 3` only. Would you kindly put the code please?

Comment: I put in my whole code. See above. Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked out very well. Thank you so much & sorry for my late reply.